# How to define default namespace for custom controls in Android axml file?

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a lot of axml files with custom controls. This controls defines in myapp.xxx namespace. So, my axml-files looks like:

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
             <myapp.xxx.CustomControl
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    ...
             />
    </ScrollView>
```

Now I want use this controls without namespaces, such as:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
         <CustomControl
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ...
         />
</ScrollView>
```

But I have an exception when app renders this layout:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class CustomControl
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try reference custom controller with name or class tag it should work

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
         <CustomControl
                class="myapp.xxx.CustomControl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ...
         />
</ScrollView>
```